# android-maven integration-test deploy not finding jar library at run-time

Tags: android, maven, continuous-integration, android-testing

We are attempting to get some continuous integration testing online for an android library (.jar file, but not an android project with the library flag set) that we have written.  I have created a test android project in IntelliJ and have managed to get the tests running fine through IntelliJ on the android emulator.

After adding Maven support, getting the POM file correct, and getting maven to build and deploy the test solution to the android emulator using android-maven-plugin v3.5.3, I get the following runtime error (and a lot more exactly like it):

```
04-18 04:41:10.800: WARN/dalvikvm(1532): VFY: unable to resolve static method 35: Lcom/joobworld/joobmobile/network/HttpResult$HttpVerb;.valueOf (Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/joobworld/joobmobile/network/HttpResult$HttpVerb;
```

The pom references the "missing" library in the following way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.joobworld.joobmobile</groupId>
    <artifactId>JoobMobile</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

As mentioned, maven makes no complaints when building or deploying the testing solution.  It populates the jar library from our local repository into the .m2 folder correctly, so it seems like for some reason it is not including the jar file in the apk.  I'm fairly new to maven so may have missed something obvious in the settings.  Any help resolving this run-time dependency issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use maven, but I have the manual solution.

You can copy your .jar on /libs folder and they will be automatically included in the .apk. Be careful: your build system may delete them automatically!

Answer (score 0):

You have the scope set to "provided" which tells maven not to include the jar in the apk. Try using compile or removing scope tag which defaults to compile.